# ayuda , how to use concat on heidi sql?

Tags: google-chrome, concatenation, sql-like, heidisql

in version 12 of hedisql there is still concat or how to do it ??

CREATE VIEW imagen as
SELECT asset_tag.asset_id  FROM asset_tag GROUP BY  asset_tag.asset_id ;

SELECT concat_ws(',',asset_tag.tag_id)
FROM
(
SELECT imagen.asset_id
FROM imagen
WHERE imagen.asset_id = asset_tag.asset_id
)
public.asset_tag ;

The objective is that the source table that has two columns, group by column 1 and that a new column indicate separated by commas what column 1 has in column 2 (of origin).

columna 1 - 1   1   2  2  3  3 4  4
columna 2 - a   b   c  a   d  a  f  g

and in a new column or table 1 - a   b   / 2 - b   c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered your question in the [HeidiSQL forum](https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=39726#p39749). And to clarify a misunderstanding: `CONCAT()` is a function provided by the database server (MySQL), not the client (HeidiSQL). So you can ignore the HeidiSQL version for that issue.